# How to change this program to search for the value in a certain cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am unfamiliar with the VBA language. I am trying to write a Macro for an MS Excel file that searches through one sheet, then posts the results in another sheet.

I have found a video on YouTube by **Chester Tugwell**, that searches for a predetermined word that is found within the Macro script.

This is the code I have after trying to modify the macro script

```vb
Sub SearchForWord()

Dim SearchCol As Range
Dim SearchWord As Range
Dim PasteCell As Range

Set SearchCol = Sheet2.Range("D7:D100")

For Each Status In StatusCol

  If Sheet1.Range("C4") = "" Then
    Set PasteCell = Sheet1.Range("C4")
  Else
    Set PasteCell = Sheet1.Range("C4").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
  End If
    
    If Status = Sheet1.Range("C3") Then Status.Offset(1,2).Resize(1, 3).Copy PasteCell

Next Status
        
End Sub
```

What I am trying to achieve, I enter a word in a cell, in this case cell **C3** in Sheet 1, then at the press of a button, it searches for all occurrences of that word in a predetermined column instead, then pastes that cell and the next 2 cells in the row in sheet 1.

Comment: `For Each Status In StatusCol` what is `StatusCol`?  Please consider using `Option Explicit` to save yourself from this type of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SearchForWord()

    Dim SearchCol As Range, Status As Range
    Dim PasteCell As Range, srch
    
    Set SearchCol = Sheet2.Range("D7:D100")
    
    Set PasteCell = Sheet1.Cells(rows.count, "C").End(xlUp)
    If PasteCell.row < 4 Then Set PasteCell = Sheet1.Range("C4")
    
    srch = Sheet1.Range("C3").Value 'only need to read this once
    
    For Each Status In SearchCol.Cells
        If Status.Value = srch Then
            Status.Offset(1, 2).Resize(1, 3).Copy PasteCell 'copy cells
            Set PasteCell = PasteCell.Offset(1) 'next paste position
        End If
    Next Status
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I needed to change a few things so it showed what I wanted, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy (Partially) Matching Rows (Loop Through Cells)

[image]

```
Sub CopyMatchingRows()

    ' Define constants.
    Const COPY_COLUMNS As String = "D:F" ' "F:H" ???

    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Sheet2
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = sws.Range("D7:D100")
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = scrg.EntireRow.Columns(COPY_COLUMNS)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srrg.Columns.Count
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Sheet1
    Dim dcCell As Range: Set dcCell = dws.Range("C3")
    Dim drCell As Range: Set drCell = dcCell.Offset(1)
    Dim dStr As Variant: dStr = CStr(dcCell.Value)
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim surg As Range, scCell As Range, sStr As Variant
    
    ' Combine matching cells into a range union.
    For Each scCell In scrg.Cells
        sStr = CStr(scCell.Value)
        If InStr(1, sStr, dStr, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ' contains
        ' or
        'If StrComp(sStr, dStr, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' is equal
            If surg Is Nothing Then
                Set surg = scCell
            Else
                Set surg = Union(surg, scCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next scCell
    
    ' Check the range union (No matches?).
    If surg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The word """ & dStr & """ was not found in range """ _
            & scrg.Address(0, 0) & """ of sheet """ & sws.Name & """!", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
                
    ' Copy.
    Intersect(surg.EntireRow, srg).Copy drCell
    
    ' Clear below.
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = surg.Cells.Count
    drCell.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - drCell.Row - drCount + 1, cCount) _
        .Offset(drCount).Clear
        
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Rows containing """ & dStr & """ copied from sheet """ _
        & sws.Name & """ to sheet """ & dws.Name & """.", vbInformation
        
End Sub
```